# Multi-processing cpu utilization estimate

Tags: operating-systems

I find a formula on my book to estimate cpu utilization under multi-processing.

$ U = 1 - P^n $

U: cpu utilization
P: cpu idle

I want to know why or how to proof.

Edit:

The book is about operating system, not in english.

This may be like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328619/calculate-cpu-utilization/20328695?noredirect=1#comment88673153_20328695

I get an answer that is

> it's just basic probability theory

Comment: What book? What are these variables? There is no proof afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P^n$ is the probability that all "cores" are idle simultaneously, hence $1-P^n$ is the probability that at least one core is in use.

Comment: @Vonfry: This is what can be imagined form the little you provide.

Comment: why using $ P^n $, not $ nP $ or others? Just experienced?

Comment: @Vonfry: elementary probabilities.